# Why is my second method's mock affecting the first method?

Tags: java, testing, jmockit

The class I've written has two methods, the second method containing a forced exception mock. When I run the tests separately they both pass but when they're run together the forced exception is called in the first method. I've tried tearDown but this method isn't available.

```
public class LambdaHandlerTest {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Testing the handleRequest")
    void testTheHandleRequest() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        new MockUp<ProviderEvents>(){

            @Mock
            public File fetchFile(String bucket, String jobName, Context context) throws IOException{
                File file = new File ("src/test/resources/testEmailFile.txt");

                return file;
            }
        };

        new MockUp<AbstractAmazonSimpleEmailService>(){

            @Mock
            SendEmailResult sendEmail(SendEmailRequest var1){

                return null;
            }
        };

        LambdaHandler lambdaHandler = new LambdaHandler();

        assertEquals ("Finished handleRequest()", lambdaHandler.handleRequest(generateS3Event(), null));
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test catch block of handleRequest")
    void testCatchBlockHandleRequest() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        LambdaHandler lambdaHandler = new LambdaHandler();
        S3Event s3Event = generateS3Event();

        new MockUp<ServiceEvents>() {
            @Mock
            public Boolean extractJson(S3Event event, Context context) throws Exception {
                throw new Exception("Forced Exception");
            }
        };

        assertEquals("Error with handleRequest()", lambdaHandler.handleRequest(s3Event, null));
    }

    public S3Event generateS3Event() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResource("s3Event.json")).toURI());
        S3Event s3Event = new ObjectMapper().readValue(file, S3Event.class);

        return s3Event;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it was happening but in the end I used @order to make sure the test with the mock that was throwing the forced exception was run last. Did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

INstead of having two method can you method the secod method to first one and check if both assert statement are excuted